# U-SQL erroring during date conversion

Tags: u-sql

I am trying to convert the string to datetime in U-SQL
below is the sample data

```
    "InsuranceApplication_Id","InsuranceAgreement_Id","ReferenceNumber","Owner1","ModifiedDate"
"30A29F10-31C9-4D41-A0FF-D45F4E4970FC","085EB12A-C59E-4B99-9665-8268D75BE084","706-19-11-RMO-014125","13EF0286-5B00-4DFE-BFA3-5DAE7926B933","3/7/19 9:37"
```

The code written is as below

```
@Joinresultfile =
    EXTRACT InsuranceApplication_Id string,
            InsuranceAgreement_Id string,
            ReferenceNumber string,
            Owner1 string,
            ModifiedDate string
    FROM "insuranceagreement_Join_v4.tmp"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();


@RE =
   SELECT 
      DateTime.ParseExact(ModifiedDate) AS d
       FROM @Joinresultfile;

OUTPUT @RE
TO "/insuranceagreement_TS.tmp" 
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Even tried the below code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(ModifiedDate,"MM/dd/yy HH:mm")
```

But it did not work. 
Any ideas.

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact(ModifiedDate, "M/d/yy H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: SELECT DateTime.ParseExact("3/7/19 9:37", "M/d/yy H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) AS d
    FROM @Joinresultfile;

Comment: tried..but did not work

Comment: do you het any error? *did not work* does not give me any clues on what is happening.

Comment: There is no error.Visual Studio errors out with Local run failed or was terminated. If I remove the DateTime conversion and pass just the column in the Select , the code runs and provides the output.

Comment: Just tried it in a local script, works fine. Maybe some dates in the input file are null or otherwise invalid?

Comment: got the resolution (my bad). As the first row is header  ,we need to skip it in extract .   Then the conversion function will work.                                                                                                       @Joinresultfile =
    EXTRACT InsuranceApplication_Id string,
            InsuranceAgreement_Id string,
            ReferenceNumber string,
            Owner1 string,
            ModifiedDate string
    FROM "insuranceagreement_Join_v4.tmp"
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1,quoting: true);                                        .

Comment: Thanks Peter for the conversion function